# Как ввести элементы матрицы/массива через Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Для ввода элементов использую `DataGridView`. Посмотрел множество примеров использования, но когда пытаюсь сделать что-то в собственном коде, при отладке сам компонент `DataGridView` представляется в виде серого прямоугольника без каких-либо столбцов и строк. В качестве источника данных этот компонент видит только главную форму программы `Form1`. Что необходимо отредактировать в списке свойств и добавить в код, чтобы была возможность ввести элементы и считать их?

На примере ввода массива с дальнейшей его обработкой (`arrayGrid` - объект `DataGridView`):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrayGrid.RowCount = 1;
        arrayGrid.ColumnCount = SIZE;

        arrayGrid.Rows.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            arrayGrid.Columns.Add("column" + i.ToString(), i.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            arr[i] = int.Parse((string)arrayGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value);

        int min = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
            if (arr[i] < min)
                min = arr[i];

        label3.Text = min.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из самых простых способов - использовать `DataTable`.

```
dataTable = new DataTable();

// Количество столбцов
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(int)); // укажите нужный тип данных матрицы

// Количество строк
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());

dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

// Опции по желанию
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Далее, соответственно, вместо массива работайте в коде с `DataTable`.

К отдельным элементам можно обращаться следующим образом:

```
dataTable.Rows[0][0]
```